# is there a way to access javascript variable in code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

here's my code

```
function qtyblur() {
    var textgettaxbaseid = document.getElementById("txttaxbase");
    var textgettaxbasevalue = textgettaxbaseid.value;
    var taxbase = parseFloat(textgetsubtotalid.value / 1.12).toFixed(2);
    textgettaxbaseid.value = taxbase;
}
```

I want to access my variables here and use it in my code behind. I am really new to this so bear with me.

Comment: @user3113490..No you can not..

Comment: how about using hidden field? assign a value to it through javascript and then call the same in code behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access what you have in client side (javascript) in code bahind you need to send a call to server. You call post the form or send an ajax call on server.

Usually we put the javascript variable values in some hidden field and get the hidden field in code behind and extract the values of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

no you cannot. Instead, use a Hidden Field in you javascript function, assign a variable's value to it and use the Hidden Field in your code behind.

Comment: Oops, I am a female, no problem :) Please upvote if any of our answers helps you. Thanks :)

Comment: oh sorry.. haha sure!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Web-Method in your code-behind and pass your javascript variable to your web-method using jquery and json.